# Windows 7 Activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I sent a Windows 7 Pro x64 system to a colleague that I thought was completely configured but it turns out it wasn't yet activated. When he booted the first time it came up with a registration screen that he just hit "cancel" on and then sent me an email asking about it.

The product key is on the box but I expect I may need to walk him through the process of typing it the code and submitting. As a further complication, the system has been configured with explorer.exe disabled and only limited functionality available with the keyboard-----so I *need* that registration window to popup in order to talk him through registration.

My question is, how often should I expect that registration/activation window to popup on boot? Every time, or in several days? I'm trying to figure out how to schedule fixing his issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 activation period](http://superuser.com/questions/108949/windows-7-activation-period)

Comment: or https://superuser.com/questions/652372/what-happens-after-you-leave-windows-7-inactivated

Comment: Just tell him to click "Properties" on "My Computer" then "Activate Windows" on the window that is displayed.

Comment: I don't think this has been answered. I'm specifically asking for the time period between activation notices. Below people indicate it is either 24 or 72 hours between notices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering just the question you asked:

Usually windows prompts for activation/validation of key every 72 hours post initial login. After 30 days your windows OS session will become inaccessible if you haven't validated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `slmgr /ato` from an elevated command prompt to activate Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling this to deal with when it happens and just waiting for it is not the best approach. I don't know how limited the system is, but have you setup a way to remote assist the pc? Like using teamviewer, logmein, etc?

You'll want to take control of the pc and login with a user who has administrative privileges, so you can enter the key yourself.

If this really is not an option, windows will display it once a day usually after login.

Answer (score -1):

If you do it with a valid product key, it will activate and will not show registration. Except when it expires. Maybe that is why this is recurring.

Comment: Window licenses don't expire please use proper terminology.  Windows will inform you if a license has been activated on another machine if two machines uses the same license but otherwise once activate it will never become inactivated